# error when installing bugzilla - You must install Linux::Pid

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2, bugzilla

I followed this guide in order to install bugzilla on apache2 server:
http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/configuration.html

I installed all modules and configured all files. all went good until this section:
2.2.4.1.2. Apache httpd™ with mod_perl

I needed to add those lines in apache2.conf:

```
PerlSwitches -w -T

PerlConfigRequire /var/www/html/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl
```

when trying to finish all process by restarting apache, I get this error:

```
You must install Linux::Pid for Apache::SizeLimit to work on your platform.......
```

I searched all over the web for solution but coudn't find any instruction how to install it or solve it in another way..

Please help

P.S.

this is the exception:

Syntax error on line 95 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
You must install Linux::Pid for Apache::SizeLimit to work on your platform. at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache/SizeLimit/Core.pm line 128.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache/SizeLimit/Core.pm line 171.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache2/SizeLimit.pm line 48.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache2/SizeLimit.pm line 48.\nCompilation failed in require at /var/www/bugzilla-4.4/mod_perl.pl line 52.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/bugzilla-4.4/mod_perl.pl line 52.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 1.\n
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

Comment: Does it not install from CPAN?

Comment: I wish I knew, I am not expert in this area, just followed slowly and carefully the instructions. I saw this page http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Linux-Pid-0.04/Pid.pm  but it didn't help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go back to the [previous page of the instructions](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/installation.html#install-perlmodules), and try the command

```
perl install-module.pl Linux::Pid
```